# controlling left/right audio channel volume in a youtube video player

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, audio, youtube

I want to know if it is possible to use javascript, flash or flex to make a youtube video player that is capable of controlling left/right audio channel volume. For example, mute the left channel and play right channel audio on both left/right speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to control the YouTube clip's sound properties via the static `SoundMixer` class; specifically with the `SoundMixer.soundTransform` property:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#soundTransform

With the soundTransform property you will be able to set the `leftToLeft` and `rightToRight` properties that control the stereo mix of the sound being sent to the speakers.

For more info see the `SoundTransform` class:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html

Just be aware that Google keep the YouTube API locked down pretty tightly, so you can only control these properties as global sound settings. If you are playing multiple sounds/audio sources then you will be affecting the mix of all sounds playing within your Flash movie. You can't get access to the `SoundTransform` instances for each individual video.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just wondering if there is any existing youtube player that is capable of left/right audio channel manipulation out there, so I don't have to start from scratch. I don't mind paying for it. sample code also helps.

Comment: I have no idea if there are any pre-existing players like that. However, since the SoundMixer is a static class you should be able to take any existing youtube player and add the functionality to that. An example would be using the embedded player that Google provides: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html#GettingStarted